# Getting 403 errors on some asynchronous ajax get requests, only on test server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a function that iterates throw a bunch of input elements, runs a query to check something in the database for each, and then alters a bit of CSS based on the results. It has been working for a while now but suddenly has problems. The problem is only when it's running on the test server. If I debug in VS it works fine. Additionally, if I step through with breakpoints in the browser it works fine. It runs asynchronously so I suspect that's causing the problem somehow. Here's some code:

```
function highlight(elements) {
elements = elements || $(":input[id$='SPQ']");
$.each(elements, function (key, value) {
    var data;
        data = {
                fieldName: $(value).attr('id'),
                pkValue: $("#" + form + " #PkValue").val()         
        };
    

    jsonGetHelperAsync("/spq/Check", data, function (results) {
        if (results.wasSuccess) {
            if (results.isChanged > 0) {
                $(value).css({ 'color': 'red' });
            }
        } else displayMessage("Error!");
    });
});
}

function jsonGetHelperAsync(url, data, success) {
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    data: data,
    url: url,
    success: function(results) {
        success(results);
    },
    async: true,
    global: false
});
}
```

The error says the JsonGetHelperAsync is getting a 403. It will get the error about 10 times fewer then there are fields on the page. There is an item that is supposed to turn red if conditions are met. If the item is near the top of the page it works, near the bottom it doesn't. It really seems like some code is completing early and breaking things, but I can't figure it out. I tried lots of async/await and Promise stuff but it all breaks the same way, even if it works when I Debug.

Anyone know what I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: If this works when you're debugging it but not when you run it 'live' then you have a timing problem. My guess is that the server is objecting to the rapid series of requests. The question I ask is why, when you appear to be doing all this validation at one time, you don't bundle all the validation checks into a single request, and have the server validate everything at once?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Well, it's not a thing that is that easy to bundle, and like I said, this way has been working for a while